# Transparent Layout above imageview with download and cancel to load an image like whatsapp

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Imageview with a transparent layout above it with progress bar to show downloading progress  .just like whatsapp when receiving image into imageview

Answer (score 0):

No need to add extra layer on imageview

1) first load image using any of image loading lib like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

2) Now User starts download image at that time set alpha 0 to imageview

3) now change alpha value to according to the percentage ex. your image is 50% download than set alpha 0.50

It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#54ff0000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@drawable/close2" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> @drawable/ic_close_black_24dp

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF0"
        android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z"/>
</vector>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]